# Android: how to make key-click sound

Tags: android, onclick, ontouch

I am using an ontouch listener to catch key up and key down events. for a repeat function.  I'd like to also have a click sound when the button is pressed.  I tried adding an onClick method and setting clickable true but the ontouchlistener seems to override the onclicklistener.

How can I make a key-click sound and also follow user preferences for on-click?
UPDATE:  Thanks all.  I found my answer greping through the Android source.  In PhoneWindow.java I found a place where they are doing what I needed.  In essence, you open the audio manager and play AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK.  AudioManager.playSoundEffect only plays the sound effect if appropriate.

```
private static AudioManager audioManager;
...
audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(
   Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
...
audioManager.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK);
```

Comment: Thanks @Piyush.  I posted the working demo code at https://github.com/bebop-001/ButtonClickText.git

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own question in the edit of the question.  I'm answering here only to make my answer in the question more obvious.  as it says in my revision of the question. to make the click you:

```
private static AudioManager audioManager;
...
audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(
   Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
...
audioManager.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK);
```

Comment: Also make sure your audio touch sound is enabled or you won't hear anything.  Settings --> Sound --> Touch Feedback

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button_flip.playSoundEffect(0);
    }
});
```

Values [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SoundEffectConstants.html)

Comment: Thanks...I tried setting an onclicklistener but ontouch seems to over-ride it.  I never get to the onclicklistener unless I comment out the on-touch listener.

Answer (score 0):

Save your sound under res/raw/. assuming that the sound name is tap.mp3,
then the code will look like this.

```
  MediaPlayer tap ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        tap = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.tap);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Playing sound.
        tap.start();
    } 
}); }
```

The start() of MediaPlayer will play sound .

Tell me if it works.

Comment: This should work but it would ignore the user preferences for sound volume/enabled/disabled, etc.